# Unable to get Realm of the Mad God to start

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I have installed the desktop client for Realm of the Mad God from Steam and upon starting the game, I get the grey "loading..." bar for a prolonged period of time and then a message box with a white button but no message text or text on the button.

[image]

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue last night. Clicking the button, for me, caused it to try again, and it succeeded that time. Alternatively, you can close the game and launch it again.